# ASP.NET MVC CookieTempDataProvider: any experience?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, web-farm

**UPDATE:** looks like I've misunderstood what TempData is for and what it isn't. It definitively shouldn't be used to "keep certain session-wide data" as I asked initially (see [ASP.NET MVC TempData Is Really RedirectData](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/01/23/37947/) why). I've modified the question accordingly.

Has anyone used [CookieTempDataProvider](http://msmvps.com/blogs/luisabreu/archive/2009/03/23/the-mvc-framework-maintaining-tempdata-on-cookies.aspx) for TempData storage? Are there any caveats to watch out for (apart from keeping the session storage small)? Any issues with using it on Web farms?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use the CookieTempDataProvider for our production web site and it seems to be working really well. We have a 2 server web farm. The site has been live for around 6 months, and we have experienced no issues, although the site does not get a lot of traffic.
I use the CookieTempDataProvider to store status messages that are to be displayed when a view loads. For example:

1. User edits a form and hits the save button. This is a post.
2. In the POST action method, I save the data, then push a confirmation message into TempData. Then I issue a RedirectToAction, to a GET action.
3. In the GET action method, I retrieve the message from the TempData and put it in the ViewData. Then I do my other data stuff and return the view.
4. On the view I check if the model has a message, and if so, display it.

Things to note:

1. I am using ASP.NET MVC 1.0.
2. I am using MVC Futures 1.0.
3. The CookieTempDataProvider did not work for me as is; I had to modify the code to get it working: see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326626/asp-net-mvc-cookietempdataprovider-deserializetempdata-returns-null).