# ASP.NET MVC CookieTempDataProvider.DeserializeTempData returns null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, tempdata, asp.net-mvc-futures

I've been trying to use CookieTempDataProvider to pass a basic message between a post (entity update) and a get (entity list) using the RedirectToAction method. When using the default TempData implementation this works fine, however when I use the cookie-based version from the MVC Futures project, the TempData dictionary is empty after the redirect. This is because the TempDataDictionary is returned as null from the DeserializeTempData method. I know exactly what line of code the problem occurs on, and I know how to fix it, but I can't believe that I'm the only one to have this problem.

Maybe I'm using the wrong version of the MVC Futures project, but I've just downloaded the [ASP.NET MVC v1.0 source](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=24471) and the problem definitely exists there. Does anyone else use CookieTempDataProvider, and does it work for you?

The problem with the CookieTempDataProvider class, as I see it, is on line 62, where it is casting the deserialized object as TempDataDictionary instead of as IDictionary<string, object>. When I make this change, everything works perfectly.

Anyone else see this problem, or is it just me?

Comment: An update on this: when I run the MVC unit tests, they all pass, but when I use the class in my application, the deserialization works but it does not consider the resulting object to be a TempDataDictionary.

Comment: Further update: When running the unit tests, the object that is passed into the ITempDataProvider.SaveTempData method is a TempDataDictionary, and it is serialized as this. However, when running the MVC app, the object that is passed into the ITempDataProvider.SaveTempDatadata method is an IDictionary<string, object>, and is serialized as a Dictionary<string, object>.

Comment: For anyone interested, this bug is now fixed in MVC 3.

Answer (score 3):

Same here.  Didn't work after using assembly as is from MVC Futures.  Changing line 62 as you suggested fixed the problem.  Thanks for posting.

Comment: Yup. MVC 2.0 and bug on line 62 is still 100% intact.(And was causing the exact same problems/issues where TempData wouldn't be intact following a Redirect.)